# Query Wikidata via SPARQL to get specific word etymology from Wiktionary

Tags: sparql, linguistics, wikidata-query-service

I'm trying to get the specific word etymology from Wikidata.

For example, this query to get the word "exact" in Wikidata but I wasn't able to get the etymology part for this word.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?l ?word ?lemma WHERE {
  VALUES ?word {'exact'@en} 
  ?l a ontolex:LexicalEntry ; 
     dct:language wd:Q1860 ; 
     wikibase:lemma ?lemma ; 
     ontolex:lexicalForm ?form .
  ?form ontolex:representation ?word .
}
```

I'm new to SPARQL but I appreicate any help to even extract the other attributes such as audio.

Comment: do you have a specific example for what you are looking for? Ideally with the corresponding Wikidata entity as you can only query for data that exists in Wikidata.

Comment: I mentioned an example the word is "exact" as you can see in the query and I want to get the etymology for that word.

Comment: also I checked the Wiktionary for that word, and there is etymology for it

Comment: Etymological data from Wiktionary are not presented in Wikidata Lexemes: see [wd:L4042](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/L4042), [wd:L12706](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/L12706).
See also https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Lexicographical_data/Ideas_of_tools#Etymology_graph.
You can try to extract and parse etymological data from Wiktionary using MWAPI, but I'm not sure it is easy or even possible.